# How to store token on server side [Angular Universal]

Tags: angular, express, universal, universal-cli

I found this post: https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/272 where user @gdi2290 explain how to add that functionalty

But I get error in my code:

> /home/master/Documents/rs-dash/dist/server/server.bundle.js:317 throw
>   new Error("Module build failed: Error:
>   /home/master/Documents/rs-dash/src/app/app.node.module.ts (97,48):
>   Property 'injector' does not exist on type
>   'ApplicationRef'.)\n/home/master/Documents/rs-dash/src/app/app.node.module.ts
>   (97,61): Cannot find name 'YourServiceWithState'.)\n    at
>   _checkDiagnostics (/home/master/Documents/universal-cli/packages/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.ts:115:15)\n
>   at
>   /home/master/Documents/universal-cli/packages/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.ts:140:17");
>   ^

I added in node module:

```
constructor(public appRef: ApplicationRef) {

    }
    // lives in your node main module
    universalDoDehydrate(universalCache) {
        var yourServiceWithState = this.appRef.injector.get(YourServiceWithState)
        var key = 'yourServiceWithState._state'
        universalCache[key] = yourServiceWithState._state.justOneProp
    }
```

and in browser module:

```
constructor(public appRef: ApplicationRef) {
        // lives in your browser main module
        var key = 'yourServiceWithState._state'
        if (UNIVERSAL_CACHE[key]) {
            localStorage[key] = UNIVERSAL_CACHE[key]
        }
    }
```

Anyone know what is problem, I am using `universal-cli`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue and developed a cache & server-side solution for it (4 separate packages for cache operations both on server and browser platforms).

Check the implementation at [ng-seed/universal](https://github.com/ng-seed/universal). Everything is handled via the `@Cached(...)` decorator on the method/loader/etc which you want it to be cached. Also, there's the possibility to use caching methods (`has`, `get`, `set`) using the caching API.

Here are the packages you need to use, for server-side caching:

- [@ngx-cache/core](http://github.com/ngx-cache/core): cache utility
- [@ngx-cache/platform-browser](http://github.com/ngx-cache/platform-browser): SPA/Browser platform implementation
- [@ngx-cache/platform-server](http://github.com/ngx-cache/platform-server): server platform implementation
- [@ngx-cache/fs-storage](http://github.com/ngx-cache/fs-storage): storage utility (required for server platform)

Comment: Thanks, could you show steps for integration on universal cli and usage?

Comment: I think this week I'll post an article about it, still busy with writing the documentation for those repo's.

Comment: That would be great, thanks! Universal cli implementation would be very useful.

Comment: Hi @Vladimir, I've finished with the documentation. Check the repo's, everything's explained on the README files.

Comment: Didn't use universal-cli, but it should work as long as the angular version is `>4.0.0` and you're able to manually implement/modify `server.module`, `browser.module` and `app.module`.

Comment: Thats the problem universal-cli use angular 2.2.3... And I have existing project with universal cli... Is there any alternative to send token from client to server?

Comment: I'm afraid that's impossible unless the whole `ngx-cache` project rewritten using angular 2.x references - in the case if angular 2.x support the same functionality for the server platform which exists on angular 4.x.